# Usage of Polymer 3.0 custom element from another webapp

Tags: polymer, web-component, custom-element, polymer-elements

I'm trying to consume a custom web component built with Polymer CLI in my **webapp**. I went though the following steps in order to setup a first dummy custom element with polymer:

using node v8.9.1, npm v5.5.1, polymer-cli v1.7.2

1. mkdir my-custom-element && cd my-custom-element
2. polymer init polymer-3-element
3. polymer serve

The demo app under http://localhost:8000/demo/ generated by **polymer serve** imports my custom element and is cross-browser compatible. Specifically it loads the custom element in IE 11 - which is a requirement in my project.

My question is: How can I bootstrap my **webapp** index.html to use my custom element (that may be hosted on another server) just like in the demo app. I didn't yet find documentation on this.

For Polymer Elements e.g. there is documentation under https://elements.polymer-project.org/guides/using-elements#using-elements on how to bootstrap. Unfortunately this does not work with Polymer 3.0 elements (e.g. b/c of module imports vs. html imports).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to go is the following excerpt from the *polymer init* generated demo/index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/webcomponents-loader.js">/script>
   <script type="module" src="http://localhost:8000/custom-polymer-element.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <custom-polymer-element></custom-polymer-element>
 </body>
</html>
```

The webcomponents-loader.js from https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs / npm package:

```
"@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs": "^2.0.0",
```

is also used by *polymer serve* and will bootstrap the custom element.

However, this currently is not sufficient because of issues with cross browser compatibility. I had to write additional bootstrapping code to get it to work in Chrome 65+, FF 59+ and IE 11 which you can find here: https://github.com/robertfoobar/es6-custom-element